# AKS with managed identity. Need Service Principal to automate deployment using bitbucket pipeline

Tags: azure-aks

I have an AKS (Kubernetes cluster) created with a managed identity in Azure portal.

I want to automate deployment in the cluster using bitbucket pipelines.  For this, it seems I need a service principal.

```
script:
  - pipe: microsoft/azure-aks-deploy:1.0.2
    variables:
      AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
      AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
```

Is there a way to get this from the managed identity? Do I need to delete  the cluster and re-create it with service principal? Are there any other alternatives?
Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the managed identity can only be used inside the Azure Resources. And it seems the bitbucket pipeline should have the service principal with enough permissions first to access the Azure, then it can manage the Azure resources. And for AKS, you can't change the managed identity that you enable it at the creation into service principal.

So finally, you need to delete the existing AKS cluster and recreate a new cluster with a service principal. Then you can use the same service principal to access Azure and manage the AKS cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this for anyone looking.

The OP asked here about retrieving the service principal details for a managed identity. While it is possible to retrieve the azure resource ID and also the "username" of the service principal, as @charles-xu mentioned using a managed identity for anything outside of Azure is not possible, and this is because there is no method to access the password (also known as client secret)

That being said, you can find the command necessary to retrieve your Managed Identity's SP name in case you need it, for example in order to insert it into another azure resource being created by Terraform. The command is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-view-managed-identity-service-principal-cli